# Use Multiple Character Delimiter in Python Pandas read_csv

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, pandas

It appears that the pandas **read_csv** function only allows single character delimiters/separators. Is there some way to allow for a string of characters to be used like, "*|*" or "%%" instead?

Comment: Why do you want more than one?

Comment: Because I have several columns with unformatted text that can contain characters such as "|", "\t", ",", etc.  The likelihood of somebody typing "%%" is much lower...

Comment: Found this in datafiles in the wild because `\t` was replaced into 4 spaces by some linter.

Comment: **//Why do you want more than one?//** it makes it easier to avoid *delimiter collision*, especially when you do not get to control the data  [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter#Delimiter_collision)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution would be to use [read_table](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_table.html) instead of read_csv:

```
1*|*2*|*3*|*4*|*5
12*|*12*|*13*|*14*|*15
21*|*22*|*23*|*24*|*25
```

So, we could read this with:

```
pd.read_table('file.csv', header=None, sep='\*\|\*')
```

Answer (score 13):

Pandas does now [support multi character delimiters](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

```
import panda as pd
pd.read_csv(csv_file, sep="\*\|\*")
```

Comment: It should be noted that if you specify a multi-char delimiter, the parsing engine will look for your separator in all fields, even if they've been quoted as a text. When the engine finds a delimiter in a quoted field, it will detect a delimiter and you will end up with more fields in that row compared to other rows, breaking the reading process.

Comment: Note that while **read_csv()** supports multi-char delimiters [to_csv does not support multi-character delimiters](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) as of as of Pandas 0.23.4. The original post actually asks about to_csv().  (Side note: including "()" in a link is not supported by Markdown, apparently)

Comment: It would be helpful if the poster mentioned which version this functionality was added.

Comment: You should specify `engine="python"` to avoid the `ParserWarning: Falling back to the 'python' engine because the 'c' engine does not support regex separators`.

Answer (score 1):

As Padraic Cunningham writes in the comment above, it's unclear why you want this. The [Wiki entry for the CSV Spec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Specification) states about delimiters:

> ... separated by delimiters (typically a single reserved character such as comma, semicolon, or tab; sometimes the delimiter may include optional spaces),

It's unsurprising, that both the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module and [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) don't support what you're asking.

However, if you really want to do so, you're pretty much down to using Python's string manipulations. The following example shows how to turn the dataframe to a "csv" with `$$` separating lines, and `%%` separating columns.

```
'$$'.join('%%'.join(str(r) for r in rec) for rec in df.to_records())
```

Of course, you don't have to turn it into a string like this prior to writing it into a file.

Answer (score 0):

Not a pythonic way but definitely a programming way, you can use something like this:

```
import re

def row_reader(row,fd):
    arr=[]
    in_arr = str.split(fd)
    i = 0
    while i < len(in_arr):
        if re.match('^".*',in_arr[i]) and not re.match('.*"$',in_arr[i]):
            flag = True
            buf=''
            while flag and i < len(in_arr):
                buf += in_arr[i]
                if re.match('.*"$',in_arr[i]):
                    flag = False
                i+=1
                buf += fd if flag else ''
            arr.append(buf)
        else:
            arr.append(in_arr[i])
            i+=1
    return arr

with open(file_name,'r') as infile:
    for row in infile:
        for field in  row_reader(row,'%%'):
            print(field)
```

Answer (score 0):

In pandas 1.1.4, when I try to use a multiple char separator, I get the message:

```
ParserWarning: Falling back to the 'python' engine because the 'c' engine does not support regex separators (separators > 1 char and different from '\s+' are interpreted as regex); you can avoid this warning by specifying engine='python'.
```

Hence, to be able to use multiple char separator, a *modern* solution seems to be to add `engine='python'` in `read_csv` argument (in my case, I use it with `sep='[ ]?;`)