# How to set a custom separator in pandas to_csv()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, pandas

From the docs I know that in order to save as a `.csv` file one can simply do:

```
df.to_csv(sep = ';')
```

However, I would like to use my custom separator, for instance: `:::`. How can I set `:::` as a separator?. I tried to:

```
df.to_csv(sep = ':::')
```

And got: `TypeError: "delimiter" must be a 1-character string`

Also I tried to: `df.to_csv('../data.csv', sep='\s*\:::', index=False)`, and got the same result. Thus, How can I set my own separator?.

**UPDATE**

Since I have in my dataframe `|`, I can not use such character as a separator. I tried to removed it with:

`df.replace('\b|\b', '-', regex = True)`

However, it did not worked. Any alternative on how to remove it?.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? [Use Multiple Character Delimiter in Python Pandas to_csv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31194669/use-multiple-character-delimiter-in-python-pandas-to-csv)

Comment: Keep in mind this is actually breaking csv spec, if memory serves correctly...

Comment: to not break spec, you might choose something even less common than a |, and instead use something like È if you're not dealing with non-English data

Comment: @not_a_robot check my update please. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Obviously Pandas seems not to allow this behavior.

However, if you absolutely want ":::". Why not exporting the dataframe with an uncommon character such as "|" and then open back the file and replace "|" by ":::".

That's the only solution I imagine to perform your desired result.

Comment: The problem is that I have `|` in my dataframe.

Comment: Find one character that you don't have. Try "~" or "µ", maybe "¤".

Comment: @johndoe, values containing `|` should be quoted, e.g.: `foo|"bar|baz"`

Comment: Or how can I remove them from my `df` ?

Comment: I tried to: `df.replace('\b|\b', '-', regex = True)`

Answer (score 22):

This is an old post, but I always seem to land here when googling how to export Dataframe to csv.

Although you can't do it directly with Pandas, you can do it with Numpy.

Since Pandas requires Numpy, you are not increasing your package size.

To do what you want, you can simply do:

```
import numpy as np
np.savetxt('out.csv', my_df, delimiter=':::')
```

Numpy offers a greater api to save csv files. You can even specify different separators using:

```
import numpy as np
np.savetxt('out.csv', my_df, fmt=['%.2f:::', '%f', '%s'])
```

You can find all the possible options [in the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html).

Comment: IMO, this answer is missing important details. See [the answer by Kumar Abhisek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68860788/350713).

Comment: Which details are missing from this answer? I'm happy to improve it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

my_numpy = pandas_df.to_numpy()
np.savetxt('out.csv', my_numpy,fmt='%s', delimiter=':::')
```

Answer (score 1):

After all, I did:

```
df['Col'] = df['Col'].str.replace('|', ':')
```

In order to remove it from the column. Then I fixed a different character to separate my df.

Answer (score 1):

Zipa helped me with my problem of using consecutive spaces as seperator [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50492061/5546969):

> This could be a workaround:
>
> ```
>   myCsv = df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: '   '.join(x), axis=1)
>   myCsv.rename('   '.join(df.columns)).to_csv(file, header=True, index=False)
> ```

Maybe based on his answer ,try :

```
myCsv = df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: ':::'.join(x), axis=1)
myCsv.rename(':::'.join(df.columns)).to_csv(file, header=True,index=False)
```

It did work for me, if te column names are strings

Answer (score 0):

Pandas version 0.24.2. Putting comment by Jonathan Dekhtiar as an answer. Saving the csv with special characters like α works like a charm