# Write .csv file from pandas dataframe with consecutive spaces as delimiter

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I want to write a text file which is separated by four spaces instead of one tab:

```
df.to_csv(file,sep= '\s\s\s\s')
```

instead of

```
df.to_csv(file,sep= '\t')
```

I tried regex :

```
df.to_csv(file,sep= r'\s{4}')
```

which did not work either ?

Is this doable without writing and the replacing the delimiter?

Comment: I think when writing a csv, `sep=` must be only one character, so not sure 4 spaces is possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be a workaround:

```
myCsv = df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: '   '.join(x), axis=1)
myCsv.rename('   '.join(df.columns)).to_csv(file, header=True, index=False)
```

Comment: Yeah , that was also my next step to add columns of spaces in between each data column and then write the file. Your solution works as long as the column names are strings

Comment: As a quick follow up: I tried to replace the `astype(str)` with `.to_string(float_format = '%09.2f')` , since it want to have a certain format of the values in the file. But to no sucess sucess