# How to write a pandas df to text with multiple whitespaces

Tags: python, pandas, text

I want to write a pandas dataframe to text file but I want 14 whitespaces between each column instead of 1.

I tired using  `df.to_csv(filename,sep=' ', index=False, header=False)`,
but there was only one whitespace between the columns and I need 14.

Below is the first few lines of the text file as it looks at the moment.

```
ppk_0000 100.0 100.0 1.0 
ppk_0001 200.0 100.0 1.0 
ppk_0002 300.0 100.0 1.0 
ppk_0003 400.0 100.0 1.0
```

And this is how I would like the text file to look:

```
ppk_0000              1.0000000000E+02      1.0000000000E+02       1           
ppk_0001              2.0000000000E+02      1.0000000000E+02       1             
ppk_0002              3.0000000000E+02      1.0000000000E+02       1            
ppk_0003              4.0000000000E+02      1.0000000000E+02       1
```

Comment: The [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) says the the sep should be of length 1. A quick and dirty fix would be to use an uncommon character as a sep (like '#') and then open the file and replace them all with 14 whitespaces.

Comment: Is there any particular reason to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Write .csv file from pandas dataframe with consecutive spaces as delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50491499/write-csv-file-from-pandas-dataframe-with-consecutive-spaces-as-delimiter) You can use the answer posted there with `lambda x: (14*' ').join(x), axis=1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To save out.txt with 10 characters wide columns, you can do the following:

```
 with open('out.txt', 'w') as f: df.to_string(f, col_space=10)
```

I hope it helps

Comment: This solution provides a fixed column width file and not a multi-character separated one. It works only if the fields have a constant length across all records.

Comment: Hmm, yes this seems to be the case.

Comment: Thanks, that made it a lot better.  It is not quite 14 spaces but hopefully it will work.  The reason I need it with 14 spaces is that the text file is input into a program that reads a file with that specific format.