# Write csv with a comma as decimal separator in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, number-formatting

How can I write a CSV file in Python with comma as a decimal separator? This problem looks simple, but I've been spending many hours today and can't solve it (googleing, search here in stackoverflow...).

This doesn't work:

`file.to_csv('file.csv', index = False, sep = ";", float_format = ",")`

In output csv still have ".".

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43324461/how-to-set-a-custom-separator-in-pandas-to-csv

Answer (score 5):

You can save with commma directly using `decimal= ","`.
This is especified in [pandas.DataFrame.to_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) documentation.

The following code should work:

```
file.to_csv('file.csv', index = False, sep = ";", decimal= ",")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of the pandas [to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#pandas-dataframe-to-csv) method and use the **decimal** parameter to designate the comman "," as decimal separator.

**EDIT**

Given the following code you posted the following should work:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv(r'file.csv', sep = ',', decimal = '.')

data.to_csv('foo.csv', decimal = ',', sep = ';', index = False)
```

Comment: this doesn´t work, if I use ...decimal = "," in outpuf file still have "."

Comment: but are you using the pandas module? Would you mind posting a [minimum, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the specific libraries and code you are using?

Comment: @MiroslavAdamek I updated the answer and posted a work that should work based on the minimum, reproducible example that you provided.

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv(r'data.csv', decimal = ',')


dims = data.columns[0:3]
metrics = data.columns[3:]

dims = data[dims].copy()
metrics = data[dims].copy()

dtypes=np.dtype([
    ('col1',str),
    ('col2',str),
    ('col3',str),
    ('col4',int),
    ('col5',int)])

dataf = np.empty(0,dtype=dtypes)
df = pd.DataFrame(dataf)

data = pd.DataFrame({
    "col1": dims["col1"],
    "col2": dims["col2"],
    "col3": dims["col3"],
    "col4": dims["col4"],
    "col4": dims["col4"]})

df = df.append(data)

df[['col1',
    'col2',
    'col3']] = df[['col1',
    'col2',
    'col3']].replace('\;', ',', regex = True)

df[['col4',
    'col5']] = df[['col4',
    'col5']].replace('\.', ',', regex = True)

df = df.applymap(str)

df.to_csv('new_file.csv', index = False)
```

Comment: @Daniel Ocando can you look at my solution and make short review please?

Comment: the code seems really file dependant? How is the CSV file you read the data from?

Answer (score 0):

My code (I need only read csv with decimas as "." and save with ","):

```
import pandas as pd

file = pd.read_csv(r'file.csv', decimal = ',')

file = file.copy().replace(".", ",")

file.to_csv('file_updated.csv', index = False, sep = ";", decimal = ",")
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed it by changing the data format for the dataframe to numeric.

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('OLS_results.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
    df1 = df1.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')
    df1.to_excel(writer)
```