# Python: importing double pipe csv pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm using Python 3.7. I'm trying to import a double pipe delimited .txt file into Python using pandas.

My code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
avm_sample = pd.read_csv(_avm_sample_file,sep='|')
```

I end up getting multiple blank columns, because of the double pipe delimiter.

If there any easy way to delimit the file? Or, alternatively, a better way to import the data into a pandas dataframe? The file itself is over a GB.

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: Seems like you can use `pd.read_table(_avm_sample_file, sep='\|\|')` as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43900308/5858851) but according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45572218/5858851) `read_csv` supports multi char separators.

Answer (score 3):

When you set `'|'` as the separator, then, naturally, `||` will be interpreted as two separators with a blank column in between. You just need to change your code to

```
avm_sample = pd.read_csv(_avm_sample_file,sep='\|\|')
```

(as pault correctly remarked below, the backslashes are needed here because if the separator is not single character, it is treated as a regular expression, and `|` has special meaning in regular expressions.)

**Example**

```
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd

TESTDATA = StringIO("""a||b
    1||4
    2||6
    """)

>>> pd.read_csv(TESTDATA, sep="\|\|")
    a   b
0   1   4
1   2   6
```

Comment: @pault Many thanks - I updated my answer already because of that. You're right.

Comment: @pault Thanks! Another good point. I updated it.