# Separating CSV file which contains 3 spaces as delimiter

Tags: python, python-3.x, import-from-csv

I'm working on a broken CSV file which uses 3 blanks as a separation. Is there any possible way to delimit it as tabs with python3?
Currently my code looks like this:

```
import csv
with open ("example.csv", "r") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter ="\   ")

    with open("new_example.csv","w") as new_file:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(new_file, delimiter="\t")

        for line in csv_reader:
        csv_writer.writerow(line)
```

With this I'm getting the error that it's only possible to delimit it with 1-character. Another problem is, that the cells in the csv-file often contain 1 blank (shouldn't be separated).

Comment: Have you tried [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)? It is usually robust.

Comment: don't bother with `csvreader` just use `string.replace`?

Comment: I think this will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31194669/use-multiple-character-delimiter-in-python-pandas-to-csv

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use Multiple Character Delimiter in Python Pandas to\_csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31194669/use-multiple-character-delimiter-in-python-pandas-to-csv)

Answer (score 3):

Well if `pandas` is viable for you, this should sort you out:

```
import pandas as pd

inFile = pd.read_csv('example.csv', sep='\s+')
inFile.to_csv('new_example.csv', sep='\t')
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error says `csv` can only separate on one character and it is probably of no use here. Just use `.replace` to turn sequences of three spaces into tabs.

```
with (open("example", "r") as csv_file,
      open("new_example.csv", "w") as new_file):
    for line in csv_file:
        new_file.write(line.replace('   ', '\t'))
```