# "delimiter" must be a 1-character string

Tags: python, csv, delimiter

I am trying to write my data in a CSV file. I require fields to be delimited by "~|". But CSV package only accepts a single character delimiter.

This is the error received while writing to the file.

```
typeError: "delimiter" must be a 1-character string
```

My code snippet:

```
cursor.execute("""{}""".format(query))

with open(file_name, 'w') as fout:
    writer = csv.writer(fout, delimiter=str('*|'), lineterminator="\n")
    writer.writerow([ i[0] for i in cursor.description ]) # heading row
    writer.writerows(cursor.fetchall())
```

I tried this approach:

1. Writing to a file with 1-character delimiter i.e. "|"
2. Again reading the above file and replacing "|" with "*|"
3. Writing the above data to a new file

The problem with this approach is that it is very inefficient and wastage of I/O operations.

Help me find an efficient way to use a 2-character delimiter.

Comment: what is your use case? what are you trying to achieve by using this delimiter?

Comment: The thing about the delimiter is that there needs to be a rule about how to escape any occurrences within a cell. Is it possible to have embedded "~|" and how would you deal with them?

Comment: If you want to use pandas this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31194669/use-multiple-character-delimiter-in-python-pandas-read-csv/45572218

Comment: If you're willing to use two passes, one of which is simple string replacement, you can just do that simple replacement as a 2-character insertion.  Skip the first pass -- don't use the `csv` package for output.

Comment: Conversely, if you can guarantee that the delimiter doesn't occur within the fields, you don't really need the `csv` library here. Just `print(delimiter.join(fields))`